# Magento 1.9 core seesion message vanishing on home page

Tags: php, session, magento, magento-1.9

I'm setting a message to core session from controller and redirect to home page
Ex -

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
$session->addError('This is test message');
$this->_redirect('/');
```

But it's not display on home page, i checked xml files and other blocks too but can't find any clue.
When i debug the message on home page phtml file it shows like this

```
 $messages=Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->getMessages();
    var_dump($messages);

object(Mage_Core_Model_Message_Collection)#77 (2) { 
["_messages":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_lastAddedMessage":protected]=> object(Mage_Core_Model_Message_Error)#76 (6) { 
["_type":protected]=> string(5) "error" ["_code":protected]=> string(34) "This is test message" ["_class":protected]=> string(0) "" ["_method":protected]=> string(0) "" 
["_identifier":protected]=> NULL ["_isSticky":protected]=> bool(false) } }
```

Anyone know how to fix this issue, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

//A Success Message

> Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess("Some success
> message");

//A Error Message

> Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError("Some error message");

//A Info Message (See link below)

> Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice("This is just a FYI
> message...");

//These lines are required to get it to work

> session_write_close(); //THIS LINE IS VERY IMPORTANT!
> $this->_redirect('module/controller/action');

// or

> $url = 'path/to/your/page'; $this->_redirectUrl($url);

This will work in a controller, but if you're trying to redirect after output has already been sent, then you can only do that through javascript:

```
<script language=”javascript” type=”text/javascript”>
window.location.href=”module/controller/action/getparam1/value1/etc"";
</script>
```